# Why is getMeasuredHeight() not returning the exact value?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

I want to set the height of the `dialog fragment` by finding the height of the layout.

That's `five heights` in the view.

I couldn't get the height of the layout using `getHeight()`.

I for this I used `getMeasuredHeight(`). (`getHeight()` only returned 0.)

But `getMeasuredHeight()` doesn't seem to return the exact value either.

I tried to set it to a height of `5` times this layout, but the actual height is
Less than 5 heights are set. (Please refer to the photo)

Why is it like this?

[image]

***writing_comment_xml***

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragment.WritingCommentDialogFragment">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/comment_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_bullet_point"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="22"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
       app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </EditText>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

***EDITED***

***DialogFragment.java***

```
public class WritingCommentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements CommentModel.EditInputListener {
    OnBackPressedCallback callback;

    LinearLayout commentContainer; // input layout
    private final List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_writing_comment_dialog, container, false);
        bindViews(view);
        addCommentItem();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setDialogSize();
    }

    private void bindViews(View v) {
        commentContainer = v.findViewById(R.id.container);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        return dialog;
    }
    
    private void setDialogSize() {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.writing_comment_item, null, false);

        new Handler().post(() -> {
            int size = v.getHeight() * 5;
            getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(1000, size);
        });
    }
}
```

---

***ADDED***

***Layout Inspector***
[image]

***fragment_writing_comment_dialog.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".fragment.WritingCommentDialogFragment">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the underlying issue is that the dialog will slip inside another *ViewGroup* called the *decorView* which has some padding that is shrinking the dialog. Here is a simplified version of your code that resizing the dialog's window appropriately so the dialog is the size you want. Comments in the code explain things a little more.

```
public class WritingCommentDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setWindowSize();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_writing_comment_dialog, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    private void setWindowSize() {
        int[] widthHeight = getDialogSize();
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        // Our dialog will go inside the decorView which may have padding. So, the window has
        // to be the width of our dialog plus the padding.
        View decorView = window.getDecorView();
        int horizontalPadding = decorView.getPaddingStart() + decorView.getPaddingEnd();
        int verticalPadding = decorView.getPaddingTop() + decorView.getPaddingBottom();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
        lp.width = widthHeight[0] + horizontalPadding;
        lp.height = widthHeight[1] + verticalPadding;
        window.setAttributes(lp);
    }

    private int[] getDialogSize() {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.writing_comment_item,
                        (ConstraintLayout) getView(),   // This is the parent.
                        false);             // Don't attach the view to the parent.

        // Measure one of the five child views to be added. The width is match_parent and the
        // height is wrap_content.
        v.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
        return new int[]{DIALOG_WIDTH, height * 5};
    }

    private static final int DIALOG_WIDTH = 1000; // Maybe should be dp?
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this before, but it didn't do any computation to get 5 heights.

Comment: @ybybyb It would be helpful if you would show the code where you took this approach.

Comment: In addition, I want to set the size of the dialog to a completely different layout size than the layout that inflates the fragments.

Comment: @ybybyb So you want to pre-size the dialog based upon the size of the five items that will be added to the dialog's view but are not part of it when the dialog's view is first inflated? Is that right?

Comment: yes, right!.. I used `getMeasuredHeight()` because the answer came out saying that it cannot be obtained with `getHeight()`.

However, it works similarly, but the 5 heights are not set as in the photo.

Comment: @ybybyb This is a little involved. What does _fragment_writing_comment_dialog_ look like. Is it also a _ConstraintLayout_? It also not clear how the view are added to the dialog. I suggest that you use Android Studio/s _Layout Inspector_ to look at the displayed layout. You will be able to see all measurements and margins and, hopefully, can determine the issue.

Comment: i posted picture and code. 
And the inpector picture is not your code, but my code when I used `getMeasuredHeight()`

Comment: Thank you.`DecorView` was unfamiliar, so I had a bit of trouble understanding the code. I have a few more questions.
`1`.The reason why I wasn't using only `getMeasuredHeight()` was because the dialog went into a `ViewGroup` called `DecorView`.
`2`.If I want to set the `width` as well as the length of the item, can I use this `View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` as well as the height? But i tried this, but it is not set as much as match_parent. `3`.When setting the size of the dialog, I saw some articles saying that I should do it in `onResume()`. Doesn't it matter at all to do it in `onCreateView()`?

Comment: @ybybyb I don't see a question in 1. For 2, you can (and probably should) use _View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY_. like this `View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(DIALOG_WIDTH, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)`. For 3, _onCreateView()_ is the better place IMO, but _onResume()_ is OK, you'll just be setting the window size when it is already set.

Comment: `Q1`. The reason why I wasn't using only `getMeasuredHeight()` was because the dialog went into a `ViewGroup` called `DecorView`. 


And in `answer 2`, it is not about height, but about `width`.
I applied `View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY` instead of `DIALOG_WIDTH` to the first parameter and the width of the dialog window is very small.